# Glide and image resolution

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm loading an image from a file.  It's a photo gallery so I don't want the image resolution to be scaled down.  I've found this code snippet that seems to work great on my devices but I've had users complain about low res images before (That I've been unable to replicate but have confirmed they're real issues) so I want to play it safe.

Will this code snippet load the full resolution image or does it require more than this?

```
    File pageFile = getPageFile();

    Glide.with(mPhotoView).load(pageFile)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
            .into(mPhotoView);
```

For clarity:

Previously, we were creating our own bitmap from the file input stream and applying it like this:

```
Glide.with(mPhotoView).load(bitmap).into(mImageView);
```

This is when users started complaining about image resolution

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:-

```
Glide.with(imageView).load(url)
    .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .fitCenter()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
    .into(imageView);
```

Also, add this `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView in XML.

You can use `centerCrop()` instead of `fitCenter()` to scale. If used `centerCrop()`, it scales the image so that it fills the requested bounds and then crops the extra.

Comment: We're not using 8888 out of fear of out of memory errors.  Is this safe with glide?

Comment: Android recommend using 8888 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888

Comment: You can move to Fresco if you have out of memory error.

Comment: @MrinmoyMk I've used Fresco before and it's good.  But we're using the PhotoView lib which, according the github page, doesn't work with fresco